# Why can't VS 2017 attach debugger to a deployed Azure app?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, remote-debugging, visual-studio-2017

I try to attach a debugger to a deployed Azure App Service app and it gives me an error. Why is this?

I enabled the remote debugging from my app dashboard in Azure Portal, but selected VS 2015, because there is not an option for 2017..

[image]

I found the post by this guy while doing the research:
[link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/28458/remote-debugging-app-service-on-azure.html)

Comment: Did you open up the appropriate ports on the firewall too, as the message explains? Activating the debugger doesn't automatically open ports on the firewall, otherwise *anyone* would be able to connect to the debugger - a process with the highest privileges, that can read the memory of any program on a machine

Comment: Just sit back and enjoy a cold pint while the 2017 button is added in. Give it some time, all Azure services will catch up with VS2017 eventually.

Comment: Turned out that our company firewall is behind all of this. So I found that certain ports have to be enabled for remote debugging. Are the ports described here the ones needed: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt592018.aspx ?